# All Emails from Google apps to gmail marked as spam

Tags: g-suite, gmail

I host my emails on Google Apps. I have three domains there.

The **problem** is every single email I send from any of these domains, when sent to gmail, are marked as spam.

- I have configured the SPF entries, and they all include a txt entry with

  ```
  include:_spf.google.com ~all
  ```
- I have checked blacklists and my domains/ip are not included there.
- I have also tried using the smtp option on Google apps using `smtp.google.com` or the native option.

Both options do not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: When mail from your domain hits my server, I do a lookup to see if the name and the IP match. If they don't, I reject the mail as spam. Check PTR (rDNS) for MX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have found the answer.

Gmail does not like having two "include" entries on the SPF.

I had two servers there, and noticed that although all spam checkers/blacklist passed, http://check-mx.appspot.com told me the SPF as "Error while analyzing SPF data"

I removed one and left only the google one, and it seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

```
 v=spf1 a mx a:google.com include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all
```

Which is a bit different than what Google says. Add this and It will work fine now.